# How is the element denoted by *(arr+i)[1] and **(arr+i) being determined?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I can't understand how the following elements are getting determined:

1. `*(arr+1)[1]` - 7 is printed.
2. `**(arr+1)` - 4 is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    printf("%d %d",*(arr+1)[1],**(arr+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`.

`[]` (postfix) has higher precedence than `*` (prefix), so `*a[b]` parses as `*(a[b])`.

1. `*(arr+1)[1]` parses as `*((arr+1)[1])`.

   `*((arr+1)[1])` is equivalent to `*(*(arr+1+1))`.

   `*(*(arr+1+1))` reduces to `**(arr+2)`.

   `**(arr+2)` is equivalent to `*(arr[2])`.

   `*(arr[2])` is equivalent to `*(arr[2]+0)`.

   `*(arr[2]+0)` is equivalent to `arr[2][0]`.
2. `**(arr+1)` is equivalent to `*(arr[1])`.

   `*(arr[1])` is equivalent to `*(arr[1]+0)`.

   `*(arr[1]+0)` is equivalent to `arr[1][0]`.

As for the actual data:

```
int arr[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

is a bit hard to read. Better:

```
int arr[3][3]={
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};
```

In the first case, `arr[2][0]` gives you the first element (`7`) of the third subarray (`7,8,9`) while in the second case, `arr[1][0]` gives you the first element (`4`) of the second subarray (`4,5,6`).

Answer (score 1):

`arr` can be more intuitively written like this:

```
 int arr[3][3]={
     {1,2,3},
     {4,5,6},
     {7,8,9},
 };
```

`*(arr+1)[1]` is equivalent to `**(arr+2)` because `a[n]` is equivalent to `*(a+n)`.  `arr+2` skips two rows, giving a pointer to {{7,8,9}}, then the two stars dereference the first of those values.

`**(arr+1)` works the same way.

Comment: "*can be*"? Shall be! "*intuitively*"? Correctly!